# LED Circuit - Series vs Parallel

Tags: led, circuit-design

[image]

We have designed two simple LED indication circuits for one of the EV start stop switch (push button start). There are 2 rings of LED's on a circular PCB. Outer ring with 8 LEDs and inner ring with 4 LEDs

LEDs: red color, 0805, resistor: 1206

The left circuit works fine except the fact one faulty LED will turn off the entire ring.

Comparing the two circuits, what do you suggest is better?
Or how can we make it improve this design? Any suggestions?

Comment: *Faulty* comes in many flavours, including *failed open* (common with incandescent lamps)  as well as *failed short* (happens with LEDs).

Comment: Considering all scenarios, I think LED open case would have more probability than the LED short case? Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Circuit 1 allows fairly constant brightness for all the LEDs because they all share the same current.

Circuit 2 unfortunately has parallel LEDs and, unless these are very well-matched, some LEDs may not illuminate very much at all and some LEDs may be excessively bright.

You can modify circuit 2 to put resistors in series with each LED. This keeps brightness much more constant when you are not hand-picking LEDs that have matching forward voltages.

Answer (score 1):

**Circuit 2 is better for your application.**
For automotive applications always factor in redundancy.

- In config 2, if an LED fails then other LEDs will still perform the function of illuminating the push button for the end user (even partially illuminated).
- Also when it comes to fault finding in future, it will be easier to diagnose the parallel configuration.

You could break up the LEDs in LED1 into 2 separate batches of x4 LEDs in parallel, this would reduce the current through series resistor R1 and decrease the heat dissipation. This would also ensure LED1 is illuminated if there were an issue with R1.
I recommend using a light defuser to avoid spotlights around your button.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Defuser is taken care in the housing part. 

Also, I had a small doubt that a LED short would kill the 2nd circuit, what do you say?

Comment: It's low risk, and the more you split your LED banks the lower risk will remain. If each LED had it's own resistor then you would gain lots of reliablity but BoM costs and PCB footprint would increase

Comment: I've seen LEDs go short. Less common than open, probably.

Answer (score 1):

I think the left circuit is the best for your application. With the parallel led circuit, some of the leds will miss current and will not illuminate much as someone said before.
Netherless, it is better if some leds are going off.

You can add a redundancy series led circuit if you have the space. With a mosfet transistor, it swap on it if the result of a brightness sensor is too low.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the LED getting least current in the *Parallel LED Circuit* will get not much more than 1/8th the current the ones getting less current in the *Series LED Circuit* do.
Wiring alternatives include *two parallel strings of four(two) LEDs in series*, respectively, to keep some redundancy.

Comment: Yes, the resistance value is different is 2nd one, it's not updated in this schematic.

Answer (score 0):

I vote left (circuits).

First, for the series circuits to have the same brightness in both strings, R1 cannot equal R2.  One possible solution is to break the longer string into two shorter strings.  In this case, all three strings could use the same resistor value.  This also helps with the concern about a single LED failure taking out an entire string.  If the long string is broken up into two short strings, and in the board layout the two groups of LEDs are interleaved, then if one string failed open, the outer ring would get dimmer but not disappear, as every other LED still would be lit.

As has been pointed out, the right circuits will almost certainly have uneven brightnesses among the LEDs.  Beyond that, there is a much greater difference in power dissipation in the two resistors.  So not only must R1 and R2 be different values for the two groups of LEDs to have the same brightness, the brightness difference with identical resistor values will be much greater than in the left circuits.

Also, the right circuits are much less efficient.  Assume a Vf of 1.8 V for a red LED, an operating current of 20 mA, and a circuit voltage of 68 V.  In the left circuits, the total operating current is 40 mA.  In the right circuits, it is 240 mA.  At 68 V, the total power dissipation in the left circuit is 2.72 W, while in the right circuit (assuming perfectly matched LEDs) it is 16.32 W.  This is yet another reason why the left circuits are preferred over the right circuits.  At 85 V, the power dissipations, and their differences, will be much greater.

And, speaking of watts - in all four circuits, 1206 resistors will not handle the power.  Worst case is (are?) the right circuits.  R1(right) is dissipating 10.6 W at 68 V, and 13.3 W at 85 V.  At those power levels, a 1206 resistor will be another light source.  Briefly.

The best case is R1(left) at 68 V, with a power dissipation of 1.07 W; still too high for a 1206 part.

And (piling on), if you modify the right circuits by adding a resistor for each LED, the power dissipation in one resistor at 85 V is almost 1.7 W.  Again, too much for a 1206 part.

Go Team Left

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention something.  85 V is a 25% increase over 68 V.  In an LED circuit with no voltage or current regulation, that is a lot.  You don't say what the voltage source is or how well-behaved it is, but if wanders around with the coming and going of other loads, the LED brightness will change noticeably.  It is clear that you are concerned with reliability, and a switching power supply, or even a simple buck regulator, probably does not play into that very well.  But between the power dissipation issues and input voltage variations, it might solve more problems than it creates.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do some reading up on the various pros and cons of each solution. What solution is best depends on the use case and the rest of the system it is placed in. For example, if you have a 12V/24V/48V system then it might make a lot of sense to adapt the mount of LEDs in series where the combined forward voltage fits the system voltage, with some margin.

If you have ample space for large power electronics, then it might make sense to have all LEDs in parallel with beefy low-voltage LED constant current drivers. It depends.

I would recommend to check out chapter 8 of the DC/DC Book of Konwledge from RECOM Power, available for free here (you just need to create a login): https://recom-power.com/en/support/technical-resources/book-of-knowledge/book-of-knowledge.html?0

It discusses a lot of practical considerations in designing LED circuits like this, and is a good learning source. Here's one image from chapter 8 of the book, just to illustrate: [image]